# Please, how do I calculate this integrals? Which substitution(s) is/are suitable?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, substitution

> $$\int_0^{1} \frac{1}{1+\tan^2{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
>
> $$\int_0^{1} \frac{1}{1+a^2\tan^2{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x $$

How can I evaluate these integrals? I don't know which substitution to use to solve them.

I wanted to use the solution of the second integral to evaluate this integral:
$$I (1)=\int_0^{1} \frac{x}{tan{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x $$
by converting it to the integral with the parameter as I obtain:
$$I'(a)=\int_0^{1} \frac{1}{1+a^2\tan^2{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x $$

Comment: See this mathjax tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The first integrand is $\cos^2x$.

Comment: once i added the `$`s i realised this is much simpler. What have you tried? Which substitutions have you tried?

Comment: I don´t know which substitution to use. So I am stuck right at the beggining.

Comment: then perhaps add this into the question, it would actually be quite helpful

Comment: @katak No substitution needed - just a trigonometric identity. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** For the first one, you don't even need to use substitution. Use the trigonometric identity
$$1+\tan^2 \theta=\sec^2 \theta$$
and the integral will become *much* easier.

Now for the second one. Start off with
$$\int \frac{dx}{1+a^2\tan^2 x}$$
and make the substitution $x \to \arctan u$. You will end up with
$$\int \frac{du}{(1+u^2)(1+a^2u^2)}$$
Now, using partial fractions, this is equal to
$$\frac{1}{a^2-1}\int \bigg(\frac{a^2}{1+a^2u^2}-\frac{1}{1+u^2}\bigg)du$$
Now, using the fact that
$$\frac{d}{d\phi} \arctan\phi=\frac{1}{1+\phi^2}$$
You should be able to easily finish this integral.

Comment: This works only for the first.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Hence the phrase "for the first one".

Comment: Thank you. And what about the second one?

Comment: @katak I'm working on it. :)

Comment: @katak I started you off on the second integral. You should be able to get it now. :D

Comment: @Nilknarf Thank you so much! (: I think I understand it.

Comment: @katak I'm glad! If you found that it helped, don't forget to $\checkmark$! :D

Comment: I changed the numerator in the first term from $a$ to $a^2$, but feel free to change it back if I made an error.